# How do I add user inputs to a terminal command which is called from an alias?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I've been using Duck FTP CLI because it has a neat option for parallel downloads of the same file which greatly speeds up the download, the only problem is the terminal command I have to type every time is lengthy. I've looked around and tried to figure it out myself but I'm stuck as to what I actually need to do to achieve what I'm after.

What I would like is the following to happen.

Have an alias that is able to call some function (or the specific action I'm unsure of) to allow text input in two different points in the command. The full line of text is this:

```
duck --parallel 10 -download ftps://someserver.com/files/USER INPUT HERE /Users/Sereniity/Downloads/FTP/USER INPUT HERE  -u username -p password
```

So it would end up something like this within terminal:

```
duckftp [Enter]

Type first directory: /path/to/download.iso [Enter]

Type second directory: /ISO/ [Enter]
```

Then these two values would then be plugged in to the full command that needs to be run with the directory paths and then executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've looked for hours but I'm not sure at what I specifically need to do to be able to research it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an alias, consider using a [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html):

```
duckftp() {
    duck --parallel 10 -download "ftps://someserver.com/files/$1" "/Users/Sereniity/Downloads/FTP/$2"  -u username -p password
}
```

Add this to your .profile, and it can then be called in your terminal:

```
duckftp source/file.name destination/file.name
```

The function takes the two parameters that you pass to it, and substitutes them into the `duck` command by using `$1` and `$2` to refer to them.

Comment: Oh that is simple, thank you. There is one issue though is that the url is not including the / but instead putting a . in the way.

Resolving someserver.com.files…
Connection failed. DNS lookup for someserver.com.files failed.

Instead of the someserver.com/files

Comment: Apologies but I can't seem to edit my comment, but I resolved the issue... I had another alias called duckftp further down the page which I didn't notice which was overriding the one you provided, it works now. Thank you again!